# Remove element from JSON array for whole table

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a column filled with JSON arrays. It looks like:

```
Numbers
'[1,33,5,4,5]'
'[1,2,555,4,5]'
'[1,5,3,4,5]'
'[1,25,3,4,5]'
'[1,2,5,4,5]'
'[1,2,3,4,55]'
```

I want to remove all instances of 5 (not 55, 555 or 25) so it looks like

```
Numbers
'[1,33,4]'
'[1,2,555,4]'
'[1,5,3,4]'
'[1,25,3,4]'
'[1,2,4]'
'[1,2,3,4,55]'
```

I have Full Text Indexing so I can identtify the rows that contain it using
CONTAINS(Numbers, '5')

Does anyone know a quick/clean way to remove all the 5's?

I know I could use multiple replace to replace ",5]"  "[5," and ",5," but seems like a messy solution.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it without multiple `replace` is to use `openjson` and `string_agg` in a common table expression to get the values needed, and then update the table joined to the cte. Please note that `string_agg` is supported on 2017 version or higher.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Numbers varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @T(Numbers) VALUES
('[1,33,5,4,5]'),
('[1,2,555,4,5]'),
('[1,5,3,4,5]'),
('[1,25,3,4,5]'),
('[1,2,5,4,5]'),
('[1,2,3,4,55]');
```

The cte:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Numbers, '[' + string_agg([Value], ',') +']' As NewNumbers
    FROM @T
    CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT [Value] FROM OPENJSON(Numbers)) As x
    WHERE [Value] != 5
    GROUP BY Numbers
)
```

The update:

```
UPDATE T
SET Numbers = NewNumbers
FROM @T As T
JOIN CTE ON T.Numbers = CTE.Numbers
```

Validate:

```
SELECT *
FROM @T
```

Result:

```
Numbers
[1,33,4]
[1,2,555,4]
[1,3,4]
[1,25,3,4]
[1,2,4]
[1,2,3,4,55]
```

You can see a demo on [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=da938b28dad874c7a157a70bdb650e39).

However, the replace option is much shorter and will work with any version of SQL Server - even as old as 2000 (I think):

```
UPDATE @T 
SET Numbers = 
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(Numbers, '[5,', '[')
        , ',5]', ']')
    , ',5,', ',');
```

In conclusion, if you are working on 2017 or higher, and need to remove multiple values from an array, the cte + string_agg apporach will probably be easier (since all you have to do is change the `where` clause in the cte).
For older versions, or for a single value removal, The replace approach might be a better choice.

Comment: Thank you. I’ll do some tests and see which is the quickest.

Comment: Thanks. This really helped with a similar problem I had, Can't believe it was so simple and I spent hours trying out complicated solutions

Comment: @Arun I'm glad I could help :-)

Comment: I guess there is a small mistake - it should be `',5', ''` OR `',5,', ','` instead of `',5,', ''`, i.e. there is an extra comma removal in your sample.