# How can I go about replacing a number array inside a json string in SQL?

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, arrays, t-sql

The data in SQL contains a lengthy JSON string in a cell similar to this:

```
{
  "Name": "Example",
  "Results": [
    {
      "ResultId": 0,
      "AnswerIds": "[1,2,33,4,5]"
    },
    {
      "ResultId": 1,
      "AnswerIds": "[2,3,4,55,6]"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a list of replacement AnswerIds: Replace all 2 with 7, all 3's with 8's

How can I go about making a script for this?

I'm able to isolate the AnswerIds using crossapply and JSON_Query, but not sure how to go about replacing several changes in one array.

Comment: For a T-SQL based solution, you can get an idea from [Remove element from JSON array for whole table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57490929/remove-element-from-json-array-for-whole-table/57491876#57491876). While that question is about removing array members, the answer code can be tweaked to update array members instead. You could use `Json_modify` to update the entire array at once - so, for replacing all 2 with 7, you'll have to write something like `se @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json,'$.Results[0].AnswerIds',JSON_QUERY('[1,7,33,4,5]'))`

Comment: While this probably can be solved using T-SQL, the JavaScript solution Sylens shows in his answer is much simpler and probably have a much better performance than anything you can get out of the box in T-SQL. If you don't mind the round trip, I would take the JavaScript solution with both hands.

Answer (score 3):

```js
const json = {
  "Name": "Example",
  "Results": [
    {
      "ResultId": 0,
      "AnswerIds": "[1,2,33,4,5]"
    },
    {
      "ResultId": 1,
      "AnswerIds": "[2,3,4,55,6]"
    }
  ]
}

json.Results.forEach((itm, index)=> {
   const arr = JSON.parse(itm.AnswerIds);
   const replacedArray = arr.map(num=>{
      if(num === 2) return 7;
      if(num === 3) return 8;
      return num;
   });
   json.Results[index].AnswerIds = JSON.stringify(replacedArray);
})

console.log(json);
```

This is what I have done, Take the json.Results array and iterate it with a forEach loop.

You can then access the AnswerIds object of each result.

Since the AnswerIds value is a string, we first convert it to an array.

Then we loop throught that array using a map, and do the replacements.

You might want to read up on **JS maps**, and **JS foreach**, **JSON.parse**, **JSON.stringify**

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2016 has JSON support but you did not specify your SQL version. 
Using [DelimitedSplit8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function) you can do this:

```
-- SAMPLE STRING
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) = 
'{
  "Name": "Example",
  "Results": [
    {
      "ResultId": 0,
      "AnswerIds": "[1,2,33,4,5]"
    },
    {
      "ResultId": 1,
      "AnswerIds": "[2,3,4,55,6]"
    }
  ]
}';

-- SOLUTION
SELECT NewJSON = 
(
  SELECT
    IIF(i.pos = 0,IIF(i.pos>0 AND sub.string IN(2,3), x.x, sub.string),
      IIF(s2.ItemNumber=1,'"[','')+IIF(i.pos>0 AND sub.string IN(2,3),x.x,sub.string)) +
    IIF(s2.ItemNumber>LEAD(s2.ItemNumber,1) OVER (ORDER BY s.ItemNumber,s2.ItemNumber),']"',
      IIF(i.pos = 0,'',','))
  FROM        dbo.delimitedsplit8k(REPLACE(@string,CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10)) AS s
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('"AnswerIds": "',s.item)))                AS i(pos)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(s.item, i.pos+14, 8000)))                 AS ss(item)
  CROSS APPLY dbo.delimitedsplit8k(ss.item,IIF(i.pos=0,CHAR(0),','))      AS s2
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(IIF(i.pos=0,s.item,
                 REPLACE(REPLACE(s2.item,']"',''),'[',''))))              AS sub(string)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REPLACE(REPLACE(sub.string,'2',7),'3',8)))          AS x(x)
  ORDER BY    s.ItemNumber, s2.ItemNumber
  FOR XML PATH('')
);
```

**Returns:**

```
{
  "Name": "Example",
  "Results": [
    {
      "ResultId": 0,
      "AnswerIds": "[1,7,33,4,5]"
    },
    {
      "ResultId": 1,
      "AnswerIds": "[7,8,4,55,6]"
    }
  ]
}
```